# Getting This Javascript Game To Loop Properly

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

An update on the game that I'm adding more complexity to. I'm trying to create a simple and little browser rpg game for my first javascript project and I have a couple of concerns about the current code:

1) I want the game to loop according to the round number count. The game will start with 5 rounds, and after it hits 0, ends. Obviously, sticking a for loop in my function solves with with the current perimeters but for some reason nothing shows up on the page?

2) Because of my interval timer, the entire function will loop for 1 second at a time but how do I get it so each individual line in my function takes 1 second each so it looks like it's actually happening vs. a block of text every 1 second as a whole function?

Here's my code thus far:

```
var yourHP = 100;
var dragonHP = 100;
var yourattk = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
var dragonattk = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
var totalRounds = 5;

function startGame() {

    for (totalRounds === 5; totalRounds > 0; totalRounds--) {
    document.write("You begin the attack!<br>");
    document.write("You attacked the dragon for " + yourattk + "!<br>");
    var dbattlehp = dragonHP - yourattk;
    document.write("The dragon takes a hit! Dragon's HP is now " + dbattlehp + "<br>");
    document.write("Dragon rears it's head to strike!<br>");
    var yourbattlehp = yourHP - dragonattk;
    document.write("Dragon attacked you for" + dragonattk + " , your remaining hp:" + yourbattlehp + "<br>");
    document.write("Congrads! You survived the attack... Your current HP Is:" + yourbattlehp + ", and the dragons:" + dbattlehp + "<br>");
    var yourChangedAttk = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
    var dchangeAttk = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
    yourChangedAttk = yourattk;
    dchangeAttk = dragonattk;
    }
    else {
        document.write("Game's Over!");
    }

setInterval(startGame, 1000);

startGame();
```

Comment: Why are you using document.write?

Comment: There's a typo / syntax error in the last `document.write()`. The string `"Dragon attacked you for"` and variable `dragonattk` can't appear next to each other without an operator between them – most likely a `+`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski you changed the entire question and now all the comments and answers don't make sense.

Comment: @Arjun I haven't edited the question. Were you intending to @ Josh instead?

Comment: Josh, if an edit would revise most of your question, rendering any posted answers irrelevant, it's generally recommended to post it as a new question instead. Also, try to focus on one question at a time.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski oh ya it was for Josh. Really sorry for that Jonathan.

Answer (score 3):

Remove quotes from startGame in setInterval() function:

```
setInterval(startGame, 1000);
```

And also the syntax error highlighted by Jonathan and Josh:

```
document.write("Dragon attacked you for" + dragonattk + " , your remaining hp:" + yourbattlehp);
```

so your code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fun with Programming</title>
<script>

var yourHP = 100;
var dragonHP = 100;
var yourattk = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
var dragonattk = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
var yourLives = 5;


</script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(startGame, 1000);

function startGame() {
    document.write("You begin the attack!");
    document.write("You attacked the dragon for " + yourattk + "!");
    var dbattlehp = dragonHP - yourattk;
    document.write("The dragon takes a hit! Dragon's HP is now " + dbattlehp);
    document.write("Dragon rears it's head to strike!");
    var yourbattlehp = dragonattk - yourHP;
    document.write("Dragon attacked you for"+ dragonattk + " , your remaining hp:" + yourbattlehp);

}

startGame();
```

Comment: This is part of the answer. The rest is there is a syntax error: ` document.write("Dragon attacked you for" dragonattk + " , `

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of problems in there.  First, you were missing a + sign before dragonattk.  Second, you had some quotes around your method name in setInterval.

The following code works.  Checkout the snippet and run it to see everything in action.

```js
var yourHP = 100;
var dragonHP = 100;
var yourattk = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
var dragonattk = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) +1);
var yourLives = 5;

function startGame() {
    document.write("You begin the attack!");
    document.write("You attacked the dragon for " + yourattk + "!");
    var dbattlehp = dragonHP - yourattk;
    document.write("The dragon takes a hit! Dragon's HP is now " + dbattlehp);
    document.write("Dragon rears it's head to strike!");
    var yourbattlehp = dragonattk - yourHP;
    document.write("Dragon attacked you for" + dragonattk + " , your remaining hp:" + yourbattlehp);

}

setInterval(startGame, 1000);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fun with Programming</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in last document.write you missed a "+".
use,
"document.write("Dragon attacked you for" + dragonattk + " , your remaining hp:" + yourbattlehp);"

checked in chrome,firefox and IE and worked fine